# Differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider, for all $-1 < x < 1$, the eigenvalue problem $$u''+\lambda u = 0$$ with boundary conditions $$u(1)+u(-1)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad u'(1)+u'(-1)=0.$$
>
> Prove that for $u,v \in C^2([-1,1])$ that satisfy the boundary conditions we have $$\int_{-1}^1 u''(x) v(x)-v''(x)u(x) \, dx =0.$$

This is from PDE by Pinchover and Rubinstein: Chapter 6, Exercise 9 part (a).

How can I go about establishing this identity? Specifically, I have trouble integrating by parts in such a way that I can apply the boundary conditions that would cause the terms to vanish. Here is what I have so far. (I may not be integrating by parts correctly in this context, though I was basing my method on the so-called "tabular method".)

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 u''v-v''u \, dx &= \int_{-1}^1 u'' v \, dx - \int_{-1}^1 v'' u \, dx \\
&= \left(vu'\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 u'v' \, dx \right)-\left(v'u\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 v'u' \, dx \right) \\
&=vu'\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 - v'u\bigg\vert_{-1}^1
\end{align}
But I am stuck after this.

Comment: one of them, say $u,$ must also satisfy $u'' + \lambda u = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
u(-1)=-u(1),\, v(-1)=-v(1), \, u'(-1)=-u'(1),\, v'(-1)=-v'(1),
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[vu'-v'u\right]_{-1}^1&=&v(1)u'(1)-v'(1)u(1)-v(-1)u'(-1)+v'(-1)u(-1)\\
&=&v(1)u'(1)-v'(1)u(1)-v(1)u'(1)+v'(1)u(1)=0.
\end{eqnarray}